# Get result from a rendered component in react

Tags: reactjs

In react, I created a modal component which is like a yes or no question(child).
I did rendered the component from my main component but what i also like to do is to get the selected answer from that child component.

```
export default Children(){
const [isAnswer, setIsAnswer] = useState(null);
return (

<p>You are about to make a changes</p>

    <button onClick={(() => { setIsAnswer(true)}>Yes</button>
    <button onClick={(() => { setIsAnswer(false)}>No</button>
    )

}

function parent(){
const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false);
function handleEvent(){
setIsShow(true)
}

    return (
    <button onCLick={handleEvent}>Show Modal</button
    {isShow && <Children/>}
    )

}
```

Comment: The you have to use some state management library or you have the useState in the parent component an pass down the setIsAnswer to your modal component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the value to the parent as a prop. Here's a [**SOLUTION**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hello-world-forked-7ddy8j?file=/src/components/Child.js:42-422)

```
export const Child = ({ sendMessage }) => {
  const [isAnswer, setIsAnswer] = useState();

  const onButtonClick = (val) => {
    setIsAnswer(val);
    sendMessage(val);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>You are about to make a changes</p>
      <button onClick={() => onButtonClick(true)}>Yes</button>
      <button onClick={() => onButtonClick(false)}>No</button>
    </>
  );
};
```